# NSBasic/CE 7.0 Run-time Error '429'

Tags: runtime

I've just installed [NSBasic/CE](http://nsbasic.com/ce) 7.0 on my Windows XP, but when I tried to open the IDE I just got this:

> Run-time error 429
>   You don't have an appropriate license to use this
>   functionality.

What I can do?

I've already tried with versions 7.0 and 6.5, and tried to uninstall, but I always get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NS Basic/CE 8 and NS Basic/Desktop 4 use a newer version of a control. NS Basic/CE 7 isn't able to use this new control.

To fix this, you have two choices:

1. Upgrade to NS Basic/CE 8
2. Delete `\Windows\System32\exPropertiesList.dll` and reinstall NS Basic/CE 7.